# Xamarin binding .aar with Metadata.xml doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin-binding

I'm trying to bind an android SDK for voice chat (zoom sdk).
They have two .aar files (`zoomcoomonlib.aar` and `zoomsdk.aar`)

I know I have to create separate binding project for each .aar and then reference them.

While binding `zoomsdk.aar` I'm getting the below error

```
The type `Com.Zipow.Videobox.Onedrive.ErrorEventArgs' already contains a definition for `P0' (CS0102) (B14)
```

[image]

In the .aar file I navigated to the `package com.zipow.videobox.onedrive;` to the interface `IODFoldLoaderListener`

And below are the contents of it

[image]

So it seems parameter `String var1` of method `onError` is causing the issue.

And xamarin studio generated `obj/debug/api.xml` confirms it (below screenshot) that `onError` will have first parameter named `p0`:
[image]

So in this scenario I change the `metadata.xml` to give this parameter a meaningful name.

Like below screenshot:

[image]

But even after doing that I am getting same error. That error didn't resolve.
Moreover now if I see the `obj/debug/api/.xml` file I see the contents for the class `IODFoldLoaderListener` remains the same.

So changing the metadata.xml has no effect it seems.

Comment: Since you used images versus text, I can't not cut/paste an answer. You are  not using the full method signature in your metadata transform. Try reviewing section 2 of Jon Douglas excellent Binding doc: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Answer (score 0):

Your definition needs to be changed quite a bit. Here is an example that solves the same problem:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.emarsys.mobileengage.inbox']/interface[@name='ResetBadgeCountResultListener']/method[@name='onError' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.Exception']]" name="argsType">ResetBadgeCountResultListenerOnErrorArgs</attr>
```

Please note the `/interface` and `argsType` items here as your initial definition is incorrect. You would then change the parameters to strings instead of `java.lang.Exception` from my example.